# Animaton like iPad Photo APP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation

I am implementing photo gallery functionality i my iPad  app . I want to display Photo gallery like iPad Photo app gallery.

is there any external library or sample code available to do this ?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Core Animation Programming Guide

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimation_guide.pdf